# Selecting cell after search doesn't segue visually, but loads next view Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView, which is basically there for users to search from a list of names. I have search set up, so they can type in a name, and it will search that person.

When they select a cell, all it does is transfer the name string to the next view. It works perfectly fine when no one is searching, and you just select a cell in the table. However, when you search for a name, and then select, you tap the cell and it turns gray. It then loads the next display, but does not show it. Then when I tap Cancel on the search bar, it crashes the app. I am not sure what to do / what this error is.

```
var appleProducts = ["I am using a custom name"]
var filteredAppleProducts = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

 override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.loadNames()

    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Type Name Here"
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar   
    self.tableView.reloadData() 
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (self.resultSearchController.active)
    {
        return self.filteredAppleProducts.count
    }
    else
    {
        return self.appleProducts.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddSearchTableViewCell

    if (self.resultSearchController.active)
    {
        cell.name.text = self.filteredAppleProducts[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        cell.name.text = self.appleProducts[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    self.filteredAppleProducts.removeAll(keepCapacity: false) 
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (self.appleProducts as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.filteredAppleProducts = array as! [String] 
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow 
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! AddSearchTableViewCell   
    print("Going to Did Select Name!")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("didSelectName", sender: currentCell.name.text)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "didSelectName" {

        let completeSignUpVC = segue.destinationViewController as! AddUpViewController
        let selectedRowIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedRowIndex!) as! AddSearchTableViewCell
        completeSignUpVC.userObjectId = currentCell.name.text
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

error:

```
[_UIFullscreenPresentationController adaptivePresentationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f890abe6cf0
```

2016-03-02 23:57:39.775 XX 2[3282:82749] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIFullscreenPresentationController adaptivePresentationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f890abe6cf0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e1cff65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d8c1deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e1d858d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e125f7a ___forwarding_** + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e125b28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010f3e7389 -[UISearchController _searchPresentationController] + 134
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010efc3755 -[_UISearchControllerTransplantSearchBarAnimator animateTransition:] + 215
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010eb6dede **56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 2638
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010ea1a4be _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ea2c7ee _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010ea384e6 _afterCACommitHandler + 90
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0fb9d7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0fb947 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0f159b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0f0e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110d54ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010ea0e676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    17  XX                        0x000000010bccac4d main + 109
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001141ba92d start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: "I am not sure what to do / what this error is." There is a crash log that _tells_ you what the error is. _What does it say?_

Comment: @matt I just added the error.

Comment: Do you change the device orientation when you get the crash?